# Dynamic range names created at each change in column value

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a dataset and want to Loop through Column A and create a new range name for each change in the account number. The data set size is of variable length each day.
ie

```
Account1393 = A1:C5
Account1726 = A6:C6
Account2098 = A7:C7
Account2246 = A8:C9
```

[image]

I tried using an Index/Match Solution to solve a problem but determined that a vlookup solution worked better. However I do not know how to automate the creation of dynamic ranges based on account number in a constantly varying set of data.
So what I am looking for is a solution that will create the account range names at each change in column A

Comment: You'll need to use VBA to do that.

Comment: The data are sorted by account.  The changes in the account number will keep the data sorted?  Maybe after changes have to be sorted before create the named ranges?  Is ok if create the addresses in a place and use them with INDIRECT...?

Comment: Allowed empty cells between values in column A?